# how to change view controller in cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have two view controller, one is view controller of main.storyboard and the other is NSPageController.

I have one button, after pressing it I want to change view controller from main.storyboard to NSPageController.

In Viewcontroller.m of main.storyboard

```
- (void)loginButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSPageController *pageController = [[NSPageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomPageController" bundle:nil];
}
```

I have one instance for page controller then how to change view controller from view controller to CustomPageController?

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to do so is to use a `NSTabViewController` with a tabless NSTabView. 
Replace your windows NSViewController with a NSTabViewController and switch the NSTabView style to tabless (in Interface Builder). In the individual NSViewController assigned to the tabs you can use a @IBAction to switch the enclosing NSTabViewController to the other view controller as following.

```
@IBAction func switchViewController(_ sender: Any) {

        if let tabViewController = parent as? NSTabViewController{

            tabViewController.selectedTabViewItemIndex = 1
        }
    }
```

This would have the additional benefit that the transition is animated as well.

Your `NSPageController` would be one of the TabViewControllers tab items.